# Cygwin appending 'cygdrive\c' to file path

Tags: cygwin

I'm getting issues with cygwin appending 'cygdrive\c' to my file path while running a python script

The error message displayed:

```
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\cygdrive\c\Users\...'
```

The proper file path is simply:

```
C:\Users\...
```

After some research, I've edited the /etc/fstab file to include the following:

```
none / cygdrive binary 0 0
```

But this did not solve the issue, as the new file path resolves with the 'c\' still:

```
C:\c\Users\...
```

I've also tried the following to no avail:

```
none / cygdrive/c binary 0 0
```

--EDIT--
Some additional info and things I've found out from messing around:
I'm running this command as part of a make file to setup a poetry venv:

```
rm -rf `poetry env info -p`
```

Python needs to find my poetry directory in order to run the poetry installation, but the directory is not resolving properly

This command 'poetry env info -p' runs fine in cmd, but in the cygwin terminal, I get the same error as above:

```
cmd:
C:\Users\...\Projects\...>poetry env info -p
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\...

cygwin:
$ poetry env info -p
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\c\Users\...\.poetry\bin\poetry': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: `/cygdrive` is the Cygwin convention for accessing native Windows file systems.

Comment: That said, `C:\cygdrive` seems completely wrong.

Comment: Is this a Unix version of Python you're using or Windows? What does the code look like?

Comment: How did you invoke `python` with your file path ?

Comment: Added some info in the main post

Comment: Showing the code that opens the file and preps the filename would be helpful too.

Comment: You do not need to edit the `/etc/fstab`, and you should restore it. It looks like you are running the Windows Python at the Cygwin shell prompt. Instead, you should install the Cygwin Python 3.9 package using the Cygwin `setup.exe` program, and run the Cygwin python at the shell prompt. It is normal for cygwin to prepend the `/cygpath/c` to paths which are outside the Cygwin install folder tree.

Comment: @DougHenderson so it's the cygwin shell that munges the file names? That means showing more code wouldn't be helpful. If you're sure of that you should make it an answer.